# Secure Hadoop Web UI

Tags: java, hadoop, webserver, jetty

Is there a way to secure Hadoop (version 2.7.2) web user interface - JobTracker, etc. - by using the available Linux accounts of the system? My goal is somewhat similar to what the old `mod_auth_pam` and the newer `mod_authnz_external` and `pwauth` is to Apache. I found a description on [how to password protect these interfaces](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/2014/03/06/Securing+Hadoop+(HDP)+Web+UI+Component's), however it would be much easier if an additional user-password list would not be required to be maintained just for this.

Configuring Hadoop into secure mode and using Kerberos authentication would be one option, but since I have a small cluster with few users, mainly for testing purposes, it would be nice if a not so robust solution would be available for the Jetty web server as well, since my goal is just to make the web UI not public towards the world.

Comment: *"The Apache Knox Gateway is a REST API Gateway for interacting with Apache Hadoop clusters ... Authentication (LDAP and Active Directory Authentication Provider) ... HTTP Header Based Identity Federation ... Service Level Authorization ... Auditing ..."* https://knox.apache.org/

Comment: Thanks for the help, in the end I used an easier workaround, I put the unsecured Hadoop Web UI behind an Apache web server proxy, which is responsible for the authentication.